# How to margin the body of the page (html)?

Tags: html, css

I used the following

```
<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0">
```

which works only on IE6. I want it to work with firefox and opera.

I attempted the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
.header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #3B5998;
    height: 35px;
    margin-top:0;
}
.style1 {
    margin-right: 38px;
}
.style2 {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #3B5998;
    height: 35px;
}


</style>
```

```
<div dir="rtl" class="style2" style="width: 100%">
<p align="center"style="width: 92px; height: 32px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 20px; color: #EFF1F6;" class="style1"></p>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: usually you get it to work on everything else, then tackle IE6 - you got it the other way round!

Comment: `<p>` is causing your problems. Try nulling its margin too see. And check that `collapsing margins` link which Alex provided as a comment to his answer.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

For start you can use:

```
<body style="margin:0;padding:0">
```

Once you study a bit about css, you can change it to:

```
body {margin:0;padding:0}
```

in your stylesheet.

Comment: @Buffon: Then it's causing another element. I guess that you have h1 or any other heading as a first element. So null the margins of that element too or provide your code.

Comment: the code is : `<style type="text/css">
.header {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #3B5998;
 height: 35px;
 margin-top:0;
}
.style1 {
 margin-right: 38px;
}
.style2 {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #3B5998;
 height: 35px;
}


</style>

</head>

<body style="margin: 0;">


<div dir="rtl" class="style2" style="width: 100%">
<p align="center"style="width: 92px; height: 32px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 20px; color: #EFF1F6;" class="style1"></p>
</div>
.
</body>`

Comment: Add margin:0; to that paragraph element.

Comment: @Nyerguds could you please link a page that says that? As far as I know you shouldn't define units for zero.

Comment: Huh, really? Odd. Seems logical there would always need to be a unit. So, zero is a special case, then?

Answer (score 3):

Html for content, CSS for style

```
<body style='margin-top:0;margin-left:0;margin-right:0;'>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yeah a CSS primer will not hurt here so you can do two things:
1 - within the  tags of your html you can open a style tag like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  body {
   margin: 0px;
  }
  /*
   * this is the same as writing
   * body { margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px;}
   * I'm adding px here for clarity sake but the unit is not really needed if you have 0
   * look into em, pt and % for other unit types 
   * the rules are always clockwise: top, right, bottom, left
  */
</style>
```

2- the above though will only work on the page you have this code embeded, so if if you wanted to reuse this in 10 files, then you will have to copy it over on all 10 files, and if you wanted to make a change let's say have a margin of 5px instead, you would have to open all those files and make the edit. That's why using an external style sheet is a golden rule in front end coding. 
So save the body declaration in a separate file named style.css for example and from your add this to your html  instead:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
```

Now you can put this in the  of all pages that will benefit from these styles and whenever needed to change them you will only need to do so in one place. Hope it helps. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will be helpful.. If I understood the problem

```
html{
     background-color:green;
}

body {
    position:relative; 
    left:200px;    
    background-color:red;
}
div{
    position:relative;  
    left:100px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6M6ZQ/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use css.  It's how modern web design gets things done.

This is a basic [css](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) walk through.

Your html file would be like:

(really simple html)

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    <html>
```

Your css file (mystyle.css) would look like:

```
body 
{
 margin-top:0px;
 margin-left:0px;
 margin-right:0px;

}
```

Comment: i used `body
{
 margin-top=0px;
 margin-left=0px;
 margin-right=0px;
}`

Comment: @Buffon It's not useless to a large percentage of websites.

Comment: Buffon, it's seriously the only way.

Comment: You could align some colored rectangles with text in a controlled environment, take a picture, and use that as a website ;)

Comment: @Buffon, I updated my answer to show you exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS).

```
body {
   margin: 0 0 auto 0;
}
```

The order is clockwise from the top, so `top right bottom left`.

Comment: lol :D .. i already know css alex and i tried ur code it good in left and right but in `top` not working

Comment: How is it not working? Be a bit more specific (I have got to record macros for this).

Comment: @Buffon Are you aware of [collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/margin_collapsing)?

Answer (score 1):

```
<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0">
```

I'm not sure where you read this, but this is the accepted way of setting CSS styles inline is:

```
<body style="margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;">
```

And with a stylesheet:

```
body
{
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: this solution helpes for android webview

Answer (score 0):

I would say:  (simple zero will work, 0px is a zero ;))

```
<body style="margin: 0;">
```

**but maybe something overwrites your css.** (assigns different style after you ;))

If you use Firefox - check out firebug plugin.

And in Chrome - just right-click on the page and chose **"inspect element"** in the menu. Find BODY in elements tree and check its properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
the body element have below styles by default
     body {
          display: block;
          margin: 8px;
        }
     body: focus {
          outline: none;
        }

we can override this using
1. inline styles       

    <body style="margin: 0;">

2. internal styling

        <style>
    body {
    margin: 0;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: Check out here: 
Should have answer you seek. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679426/override-css-style