# HTML to PDF Page fit to HTML

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

Currently I was working on feature to convert html to pdf using `itext7`. But I got stuck when I try to fit the pdf page size into html content.

My expectation is to remove these space so the pdf will appear like the html.

[image]

This is how the html looks like

[image]

This is the code that I currently use

```
private MemoryStream _GenerateFile(string html)
    {
        ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
        converterProperties.SetImmediateFlush(false);
        converterProperties.SetBaseUri(""); 

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(stream);
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
        pdf.SetDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4);

        HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(html, pdf, converterProperties);
        var pdfBytes = stream.ToArray();
        pdf.Close();

        MemoryStream result = new MemoryStream(pdfBytes);
        result.Position = 0;

        return result;
    }
```

**Things I've tried**

- Remove page size option
- add margin:0 ( this only remove the space above the html
- add padding:0

Feel free to drop any suggestion here, Thanks.

**Update**
Thanks for the suggestions, I've tried all the suggestion is not solve my issue. Meanwhile on the half way we decide to change from `itext7` to as `aspose` instead. So this issue is not relevant anymore.

Comment: Are you sure you want this? Printers might cut off part of the page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iText 7 can not set margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47470197/itext-7-can-not-set-margin)

Answer (score 1):

The following CSS instruction sets the margins of the page to 0:

```
<style>
    @page {
      margin: 0;
    }
</style>
```