# Remove or Override the css For selected div in webpage

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS. i have page with site css(style.css) that have all the basic tag css example

```
body{color:#c2c2c2} 
h2{ color:green;padding-5px }
span{ color:blue;border:1px solid #b4b4b4 }
```

I need to remove this css for selected div

```
<div class="remove"><h3>Test</h3><span>This sample text for the css remove</span></div>
```

for remove class clear all the default site css.

Comment: Do you need to override the site css with your own or remove the entire css for class remove?

Comment: i need to remove the css only for remove class.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you need to remove the "remove" class?

Comment: Normal site have css file style.css that contain  each and every tag in html css. My problem is remove those css for selected div(remove class).

Comment: You can override the css for the class remove using your custom css which is easier to do. Check these links 
[Override CSS - Link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679426/override-css-style)
[Override CSS - Link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117126/how-to-overwrite-css-style)

Comment: override all the css of the style.css,but still the ol and ul style not change.In style css list-type-stype:none and ol in remove list-type-stype:decimal !important; but not change..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the global styles.

```
body{color: red} 
h2{ color: green;padding: 5px }
span{ color: blue;border: 1px solid black }

/*Overriding global styles*/
.remove h2 {color: yellow !important;padding:0 !important}
.remove span {color: gray !important;border-color:yellow !important}
```

Answer (score 0):

give class name to each and every div tag in which you want to add css and make a div class's css

```
div.add
{
/* insert css */
}
```

give class="add" to that css in which you want to add css

Answer (score 0):

Removing style is not a concept instead you can override the css styling.

Then you need to define style properties for the "remove" class. How you want to display it.